# Issue while saving clipboard data as image

Tags: c#, .net, clipboard, wpf-4.0

I have copied some data in Clipboard using MS-Word Com API

```
Range.CopyAsPicture();
```

and when I am pasting(Ctrl + v) it on window's paint software its getting displayed.

Issue is while converting Clipboard data to image Using c# 
I looked into various link on internet and tried following code which is not working

```
MemoryStream ms = Clipboard.GetData("DeviceIndependentBitmap") as MemoryStream;
```

above line returning `null`

```
clipboardData.GetDataPresent(System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Bitmap)
```

Above line returning `false`

Can anyone please suggest how can convert the clipboard data to image.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are looking for is getting the bitmap of the image in the clipboard (or the underlying binary data), look into using GetImage.
Here is a code snippet you can try:

```
        BitmapSource bmpSource = Clipboard.GetImage();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmpSource));
        encoder.Save(ms);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

In case that also doesn't seem to work, you can try looking into [this workaround](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/02/05/wpf-paste-an-image-from-the-clipboard/), it doesn't seem directly related, but it might be just what you need.

Comment: Clipboard.GetImage(); is returning null

Comment: MS Office apps use the string "PNG" as data format, and the data is a `MemoryStream` containing the bytes of the png image.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently MS Office puts images on the clipboard as a stream of PNG bytes, which is actually a really sensible innovation. This image data simply uses the identifier "PNG".

So try this instead:

```
if (retrievedData.GetDataPresent("PNG"))
{
    MemoryStream png_stream = retrievedData.GetData("PNG") as MemoryStream;
    if (png_stream != null)
        return new Bitmap(png_stream);
}
```